# PHP - how to add $key => $value to two dimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add a new set of key and values into a two dimensional associative array. Here is my array

```
myArray = array(1 => array("John", 500, "2012-09-02"),
2 => array("Mike", 105, "2012-07-01"),
3 => array("Joe", 24, "2011-12-23"),
4 => array("Alex", 65, "2012-08-30"));
```

What I would like to do is have user input an ID and a name than either increase value[1] by 5 if they entered data is in myArray, but if it's not than I would like to add their information as new data into the array so it should output/print a 5th $key and $values. The if statement works fine and adds 5 to value[1], but I can't seem to get the else if statement to add the new entry.

```
$nameExists = FALSE;
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    if($key == $id && $value[0] == $name){
    $value[1] = $value[1] + 5;
    $nameExists = TRUE;
        }
        else if ($nameExists === FALSE){
            $newData = array($name, 1, date("Y-m-d"));
            $myArray[] = $newData;
        }
        echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>
                    <td>".$value[0]."</td>
                    <td>".$value[1]."</td>
                    <td>".$value[2]."</td></tr>";
}
```

any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a logic flow problem with the check for `$nameExists === FALSE`.  That should be tested *after* the entire `foreach` loop has completed, rather than inside the loop body. Otherwise, the loop tests the first array element for a match and if not found right then, proceeds to append to the array.

Instead, move the `$nameExists === FALSE` to after the loop. If no match was found, that flag will not have been set `TRUE` and the array append should work.

```
$nameExists = FALSE;

// Note: use htmlspecialchars() on *output to HTML* not on input filtering!
// If you print these values later in the page, you should enclose them
// in htmlspecialchars() at that time. Placing it here may cause
// your values not to match in the loop if the stored vals were unescaped.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Note the &$value is needed here to modify the array inside the loop by reference
// If left out, you'll get through the loop and changes will be discarded.
foreach($myArray as $key => &$value){
    if($key == $id && $value[0] == $name){
        $value[1] = $value[1] + 5;
        $nameExists = TRUE;
        // No need to continue looping, you can exit the loop now
        break;
    }
    // Finish loop - flag was set TRUE if any match was found
}

// Now, if nothing was modified in the loop and the flag is still FALSE, append a new one
if ($nameExists === FALSE){
    $newData = array($name, 1, date("Y-m-d"));
    $myArray[] = $newData;
}


// Use a separate loop to output your complete array after modification
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    // use htmlspecialchars() here instead...
    // And display output values indexed $myArray[$id]
    echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[0])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[1])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($value[2])."</td></tr>";
}
```

Check the notes in [the PHP `foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) about modifying the looped array with `&` references.

Comment: I understand what your saying, but the reason it's all in the loop is because I want the entire set of values to print out from the array including any new values.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention. I tried testing the else if with a simple echo "it works!" and that printed out fine when new input was given. I think something is wrong with this part $newData = array($name, 1, date("Y-m-d"));
    $myArray[] = $newData;

Comment: The `$myArray[] = $newData;` is syntactically and logically correct, but it cannot be inside the loop. Please give it a try with my complete updated code.

Comment: I tried it too, but it doesn't print out the new input, instead it is giving me    3 => array("Joe", 24, "2011-12-23") no matter what data I enter

Comment: @Pachuca That sounds like you are not using the last version of the `foreach` loop for output. In my initial posting it was writing `htmlspecialchars($myArray[$key][0])`,  which would have been `Joe` as the last iterated item from `$myArray`. As currently posted with the `foreach` loop at the end, it is listing all values, including the new addition where applicable. I just tested it with a simple form.

Comment: I threw an example on my web server: https://www.berkowski.net/stackoverflow46869331/form.html  The two inputs are your id, name. If you enter 1, John it will output John with 505, or add an entirely new name.

Comment: is my syntax correct for $newData? Since it's a two dimensional array I tried doing $newData = array($id => array($name, 1, date("Y-m-d"))); and it still doesn't work either way. I did what you said and It does add a new element/key, but it only prints out the value that's already existing in the array.

Comment: `$newData = array(...)` without `[]` will definitely not work correctly. The syntax as you originally had it and as I have it above is correct. If you are still not getting correct output, please edit your original post to show your current updated code.  You never mentioned data persistence, but are probably aware that no changes can be saved between page views yet. Just want to be clear of your expectations...

Comment: I see what my problem is, you referenced &$value in the first loop, I didn't do that. I didn't know you could do that in php :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this was driving me nuts for days!